# How can I convert '+' character to a regular expression for REGEXMATCH in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(OR(REGEXMATCH(C3,"A"),REGEXMATCH(C3,"+"),REGEXMATCH(C3,"G")),1,0)
```

In Google Sheets, I'm using the above formula to output `1` if either `A`, `+` or `G` characters are present in cell C3. Some example values for C3 are `AG+`, `ABCDKHN$%`, `GHXV`, etc, those will lead the formula to output `1`.

The `+` character ends up with this error:

[image: description]

How can I convert the `+` character for the REGEXMATCH formula to look for it in a string successfully?

Comment: You need to escape it `\+`

Comment: Note that doing three separate matches on the same text is not really taking advantage of the power of regex.  An expression of `"[AG+]"` would match any of those three characters in a single test.

Comment: That is clever and shortens my formulas by a lot, thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(C3, "A|G|\+"), 1, 0)
```